# Is reading ISO 27000 official publication sufficient to prepare for exam?

Tags: certification, iso27001

I was at the ISO/IEC 27001 official web page. I saw a the publication for the norm. It's about 23 pages. So I was wondering if studying those 23 pages would prepare me enough, lets say at 80%, to passe exams for foundation, lead auditor or lead implementer exams ?

Comment: I suggest to close this question because the answers can only be opinion based.

Comment: @mentallurg I suggest you try to help me maybe reformulate the question instead to banning it. Somebody else may find it usefull

Comment: It’s impossible for anybody here to know what would be sufficient for you. An answer to that question is certainly not helpful to anybody else. Reworded to “does exam X require anything other than factual knowledge from standard Y” would be a better question, but still might not be within the scope of this site.

Comment: I'm surprised to see an ISO standard of just 23 pages... but [that's indeed its length](https://www.iso.org/standard/54534.html)

Comment: @stevenmiller: The question is formulated well. There is no need to change it. But this is one of the rules of SE (please read details on meta): questions that have *opinion based* answers should be closed. To your question: Some people can be prepared to exam even without reading the standard, because they know everything needed from their experience. For some people knowing the chapter names will be sufficient. For some people even reading of 100 books will be not sufficient. This is the reason why answers will be **not useful**.

Comment: @stevenmiller: Briefly: SE wants to be a source of **knowledge**, not a source of **opinions**.

Comment: Also... ISO 27000 is only 23 pages since it is only the overview and vocabulary list. There's a whole series of awful ISO 27k documents to read...

Comment: I'm closing the question because it lacks the most basic research. So, no, answers to what you've asked will not help others. First, the Lead Auditor certification requires professional experience, not just passing an exam. Second, what each org requires to pass ***their exam*** will depend on them. There isn't one single exam. Third, and no, it's not all about the content of the standard but about the activities of auditing and implementing. I found all this out with 5 minutes of googling.

Comment: So, is just reading the standard enough to pass 80% of the ISO 27001 content part of these exams? That's totally up to opinion and the particular org's exam you are aiming for. The rest of your question is asked based on a faulty understanding of what's included in the certifications. You need to be asking these questions of the orgs providing the certifications, and they have the answers readily available.

Comment: lol thank you guys. I just though those 23 pages was enough as study guide

Answer (score 2):

> Is reading ISO 27000 official publication sufficient to prepare for exam?

No.

ISO 27000 is only 23 pages since it is only the overview and vocabulary list.

Comment: Your argument on the comments was spot on. Why did you leave it out from your answer?